# Firestore import data from another project from a different location

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Currently, I am using `location US` and I wanna move to `location asia-south1` as there's a huge pricing difference in both locations and later one is also near to me. I wasn't aware of this when I created my project.

I know that it's not possible to change the region once it's set. I found that I need to create a new project and move data there, I exported my data as per [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import). But now I am trying to import data into my new project and I am facing this issue.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.firestore.import) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Bucket xxxxxxx-xx.appspot.com is in location US. This project can only operate on buckets spanning location asia-south1 or Asia.
```

What I understood is that I can't import data from another location. and it seems I am locked in the current location. If it's so any solution for this? As it's not possible for me to create everything from zero again.

Answer (score 3):

It is correct that you [cannot import data from another location](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/move-data#import_data_into_the_destination_project). Since the location of your bucket and your destination project need to be the same to properly import, you could [create a new bucket with the correct location and copy the data from your older bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/moving-buckets).

Then, you could follow the steps for [transferring the data to your destination project's own Firestore database](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/export-import). You were halfway through the process until you got blocked by the location restriction.